# Magento 2: How can I remove the attribute value in the product view page?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, product-view

I'm using `Magento 2.1.6` and am wondering how can I hide an `attribute` from being displayed on a `product view` page?

I have tried setting '`Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront`' to `'No'` from within `admin` for the `attribute`. however, it is still showing on the `product view page`.

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: You can remove attribute value manually using database.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: I need to show it in leftbar .But not needed in product view page

Comment: This should be fine doing what you have done I can only suggest however that flushing cache will remove the cached versions of pages where this setting was set to yes.

Comment: I overcome this issue by setting up all attributes values in the initial section of 'add product' page. The attributes which we needed to display in the "product view' page should be defined under "create configuration" section of the same page.